# How to remove billing address from checkout page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to reorganize elements on the checkout page. **I want to remove billing address and show only shipping address in 1st column**. And in the second column have "Your order" and payment options.

I changed this to have checkbox(for shipping address) checked. (`form-shipping.php`)

```
<h3 id="ship-to-different-address">
    <span><?php _e('Delivery address', 'woocommerce'); ?></span>
    <input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" checked type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1" style="display:none;"/> 
</h3>
```

Also I added this code to `functions.php` to disable billing fields validation.

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields)
{
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    return $fields;
}
```

And finally this was the `form-checkout.php`

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url()); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php if ($checkout->get_checkout_fields()) : ?>
        <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
            <div class="col-1">
                <?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details'); ?>

                <?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_shipping'); ?>

                <?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details'); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2">
                <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e('Your order', 'woocommerce'); ?></h3>
                <?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review'); ?>
                <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
                    <?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review'); ?>
                </div>
                <?php do_action('woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout); ?>
```

So the checkout page looked awesome! Exactly how I wanted it, but there was a problem with validation of shipping address fields. It load payment method even if there's wrong email, delivery date or phone number (if field is empty it will catch and display prompt).

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this? OR explain what is the right way to achieve my goal? Because I'm pretty sure my way is not very nice from WP and programming point of view. Thanks!

Comment: what if you set for that part display none and remove required attribute ?